# Why does the value of my variable revert in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, static, segue

I got my code working, but I don't know why it works.

Having this prepareForSegue Function doesn't work, and when my variable is called in the viewController that the prepareForSegue goes to, it returns nil.

The original VC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == K.latinSegue {
        if latinTextField.text != nil && latinTextField.text != "" {
            guard let latinText = latinTextField.text else { fatalError("latinText broken")}
            let destinationVC = LatinViewController()
            destinationVC.latinText = latinText
            
        }
    }
}
```

The destinationVC:

```
var latinText: String?

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let latinTranslator = LatinTranslator()
    let latinDefinition = latinTranslator.getHTMLAndDefinition(latinText: **latinText!**)
    textLabel.text = latinDefinition
}
```

latinText! Doesn't have a value when it is force unwrapped here, even though I set its value in the prepare for segue function.

Now, this code works. I kinda know how static variables work, so I'm just really confused as to why the previous code doesn't work - it throws a nil value not found error.

The originalVC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == K.latinSegue {
        if latinTextField.text != nil && latinTextField.text != "" {
            guard let latinText = latinTextField.text else { fatalError("latinText broken")}
            LatinViewController.latinText = latinText
        }
    }
}
```

The destinationVC:

```
static var latinText: String!

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let latinTranslator = LatinTranslator()
    let latinDefinition = latinTranslator.getHTMLAndDefinition(latinText: LatinViewController.latinText)
    textLabel.text = latinDefinition
}
```

The segue is called when a button is pressed. I have checked, there is only one segue. Please help!

Comment: Use `if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? LatinViewController {...}` instead of creating a new instance of LatinViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you’re having is that you’re creating a new instance of `LatinViewController` and not using the instance that your app will actually be navigating to.

Instead of this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == K.latinSegue {
        if latinTextField.text != nil && latinTextField.text != "" {
            guard let latinText = latinTextField.text else { fatalError("latinText broken")}
            let destinationVC = LatinViewController()
            destinationVC.latinText = latinText
            
        }
    }
}
```

You should be doing something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   guard segue.identifier == K.latinSegue, let destination = segue.destination as? LatinViewController else {
      return
   }
   guard let text = latinTextField.text, !text.isEmpty else {
      return
   }
   destination.latinText = text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it return nil because the destinationVC you create new LatinViewController not the viewController of your current segue

```
let destinationVC = LatinViewController()
```

change to this:

```
let destinationVC = segue.destination as? LatinViewController
```